# Python recursive function(flatten(data))

Tags: python

```
def flatten(data):
    output = []
    print(data, "start", output)
    for item in data:
        if type(item) == list:
            output += flatten(item) # 1
        else:
            output += [item] # 2
    print(data, "end", output)
    return output  


example = [[1, 2, 3], [4, [5, 6]], 7, [8, 9]]
print("originally : ", example)
print("transformation : ", flatten(example))
```

First, I'm sorry that I can't speak well English, so you will can't understand my explain.

Why using it 'output += flatten(item)' in the '# 1'?

Can't I just use 'flatten(item)?'

Comment: Can you share the 'C/C++' recursive function code?

Comment: @MoosaSaadat I'm afraid that's not possible. There is no C/C++ language. Unless someone's written it as a joke in the past few weeks.

Comment: This question is about the essence of recursion. So long as there is more work to do, a recursive function keeps calling itself. In the #1 case, there is more work to do, gathering the data in the list. In the #2 case, the object is not a list, so it stops. The += accumulates the data recorded all of the way back, no +=, no data collected. Your call on whether you want to leave that out or not.

Comment: I thought else: In sentences, every single object would be stored in the output. However, it was not so I wondered.

Comment: Are there multiple outputs for each recursive function?

Answer (score 0):

What `'output += flatten(item)' in the '# 1'` does is append the return value of `flatten(item)` to the output list.

Using just `flatten(item)` will not modify `output`.

Also, when I ran your code, `print(data, "end", output)` was executed at the end of every recursion.

Comment: I'm sorry... I misunderstood.
Clearly, the last sentence is executed over and over again.